# Сделать navigation bar видимым на одном экране и невидимым на другом

Tags: swift, navigationcontroller

Создал свой Search bar, при активации которого navigation bar становится hiden. Но как только перехожу на следующий экран, он соответственно остается спрятан, а нужно чтобы не был. Делать его не hiden с помощью методов контроллера: viewDidAppear и тд - не вариант, так как nav бар будет резко появляться на предыдущем экране. Вот так это выглядит как только перехожу на след экран.

[image]

[image]

А нужно, чтобы было был виден nav bar

[image]

Ну и соответственно то, для чего все это делалось (почему не использовал стандартный эпловский серч бар) - в момент свайпа на предыдущий экран, серч бар должен находиться на предыдущем экране, а не залезать поверх нынешнего, с которого переход еще не закончен.

То есть на первом экране он получается спрятан, а на втором - нет. И это все одновременно. Должно получиться примерно как в приложении Почта:

[image]

В приложении фото, как мне кажется, в этот момент на последнем экране не nav bar, а просто UIView с кнопками, но я не уверен в этом, да и может есть более приятные способы решить эту проблему, чем отрисовывать лишнюю вьюшку..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А зачем Вы скрываете Navigation bar? Просто когда начинается поиск помещаете SearchBar на NavigationBar:

```
navigationItem.titleView = searchBar
```

Результат:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: И правда... спасибо!